# VBA wscript.shell .close giving error

Tags: vba, shell, ms-word

I am using the following code (as found [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?26616-Solved-How-get-TargetPath-of-lnk-or-url-shortcut-files)) in Word2010 to find the target path of a shortcut:

```
Function Getlnkpath(ByVal Lnk As String) 
On Error Resume Next 
With CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CreateShortcut(Lnk) 
    Getlnkpath = .TargetPath 
    .Close 
End With 
End Function 

Sub GetLinkPath() 
    MsgBox Getlnkpath("yourshortcutnamehere") 
End Sub
```

When I run the code as shown (modified to use my shortcut name) I get the following error:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

and the `.Close` line is highlighted for debug. When I comment out `.Close` the script works fine.

Does this cause problems if the shell doesn't close? I've read that `.Close` isn't necessary for `Wscript.Shell` but can't confirm that.

Comment: What are you expecting `.Close` to do, exactly?

Comment: I don't need or expect it to do anything. I just wasn't sure why it wasn't working, and if there was an issue if the `Wscript.Shell` didn't have a `.Close` command. I am still learning all of this and didn't want to implement something that would cause problems.

Comment: Well, you typed it, so you must have had some purpose in mind? What are you trying to close? It's difficult to help you fix an error if you don't tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am using it to find the target path of an existing shortcut. I found the code elsewhere (see the link) and modified it to suit my needs. The code came with the `.Close` command which was causing errors. As it appeared to work for others I did not know why it was causing errors on when I used it. Commenting out the `.Close` command made it work . Unfortunately I don't fully understand how it finds the target path of an existing shortcut by creating another object and wasn't sure if it would cause problems. I am seeking clarification on how it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

There is no Close method to the shortcut object and that is why you are getting the error. This [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187429&seqNum=5) lists basic operations of WScript.Shell.

If you are intending to dispose the shell object, the best way to do would be

```
Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

With objWshShell.CreateShortcut(Lnk)

.Save

Getlnkpath = .TargetPath

End With

Set objWshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks Shalvin.   As I haven't assigned the shell object to a variable do I need to dispose of it?  Also, should the last line say `Set objWshShell = Nothing` ?

Comment: In your case, since you are not assigning shell object to variable, you don't need to dispose. Also, it was a typo, use objwshshell in last line

Answer (score 3):

**Posting this answer for anyone who is still stuck on trying to close the WScript.Shell Object after creating it and not able to find a solution.
    My Vb Script :**

```
        Dim wsh As Object
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell", vbNothing)
        wsh.Run "cmd.exe /C pause"
        wsh.Run "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe"
```